# There is error in xgboost model . What is the meaning of this error

Tags: python, pandas, xgboost

Features

```
X = df[df.columns.drop("month_5_still_here")]
```

Target

```
y = df["month_5_still_here"]
```

Split Data into Training and Test Set

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,
                                                    y,
                                                    test_size = 0.5,
                                                    random_state = 12)
```

Instantiate the XGBClassifier: xg_cl

```
xg_cl = xgb.XGBClassifier(n_estimators = 10, objective = "binary:logistic")
```

Fit the classifier to the training set

```
xg_cl.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

Predict the labels of the test set: preds

```
y_pred = xg_cl.predict(x_test)
```

Compare Actual and Predicted Values

```
pd.DataFrame({"Actual": y_test, "Predicted": y_pred})
```

```
XGBoostError: [16:42:58] c:\users\administrator\workspace\xgboost-win64_release_1.4.0\src\data\array_interface.h:139: Check failed: typestr.size() == 3 (2 vs. 3) : `typestr' should be of format <endian><type><size of type in bytes>.
```

Comment: Please format your code properly (read the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), show the [complete error message](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough), and ask your question in the question itself (not just the title), properly formatted (a question should end with `?`).

Comment: Could you share your xgboost version?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your Dataset lookslike so I have to take a few guesses.

1. Maybe there is a some conversion that Python does, for example float to Int?
2. Your Targets don't have the same amount of Rows.
3. One of your Targets could have an extra Column
4. The Dimension of your targets aren't the same.

You should try to debug it and watch everystep of your code. Check all your dataframes during the debug.